# Execute a Unix command using Cmakefile

Tags: cmake

I want CMakefile to generate Makefile that is able to execute some specific unix commands. What is the generic way to do it?

For example, I want to force the execution of this command

```
g++ hello.cpp -o libhello.dylib -dynamiclib
```

or this command

```
mdfind "hello" -onlyin .
```

The reason that I want to use CMakefile rather than a simple script is that I have one line of command that has to be inserted into a compilation process (which has already been defined by an existed CMakefile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html).  This will let you run any arbitrary command as part of your build process.  You can use it in conjunction with [`add_dependencies`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_dependencies.html) to make it run automatically.  See also [`add_custom_target`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_target.html).